# Java code to segment string into meaningful dictionary words, getting StringIndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, string, dictionary

//Here is Java code to segment a string into meaningful dictionary words. 
   Getting StringIndexOutOfBoundException!

```
import java.util.*;
public class SeparateStringWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //segment a word into meaning full word eg. iamstudent => i am student

        String str = "iamstudent";
        Set < String > dict = new HashSet < String > ();
        dict.add("i");
        dict.add("am");
        dict.add("student");

        //dict is our lookup dictionary
        String separated = segmentString(str, dict);
        System.out.println("separated string is:" + separated);

    }
    static String segmentString(String str, Set < String > dict) {
        if (dict.contains(str)) return str;
        int len = str.length();
        System.out.println(len);
        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            String prefix = str.substring(0, i);
            if (dict.contains(prefix)) {
                String suffix = prefix.substring(i, len); //StringIndexOutOfBoundException 
                String subSuffix = segmentString(suffix, dict);
                if (subSuffix != null) {
                    return prefix + " " + subSuffix;

                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

//Solved: thanks for help guys :) ..... suffix=str.substring(i,len);

Answer (score 2):

Prefix is a substring that is shorter then `len`  because `len` is the length of `str` and `prefix` is a substring from o to i so you have to use `str.substring(i,len)`;

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to get the suffix of the original String, not from the prefix :

```
String suffix=str.substring(i,len);
```

It makes no sense to try to get the suffix of the prefix, since the prefix only has `i` characters, so both `i` and `len` would be out of bounds.